# How do I align elements horizontally?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have three elements (DIVs) and I need to align them horizontally. I'm following Bootstrap's guides and it won't work.

This is what I need it to look like: 
[image]

This is what it looks now, it's aligned to the left:
[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.price-selection {
 border: 1px solid #8ABE57;
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-12 product-info-subtitle cuanto-pagar">
    <p>¿Cuánto quieres pagar?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
        <p class="price">one</p>
        <p class="period">one</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
        <p class="price">two</p>
        <p class="period">two</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
        <p class="price">three</p>
        <p class="period">three</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Columns should not be direct children of other columns. If you want to divide a column use a `.row` wrapper.

Comment: but if i want gap between cols, now what i do ? if i change  `col-3` into `col-4` i don't give space between cols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `m-0` for remove horizontal bar.

> Columns should not be direct children of other columns. If you want to divide a column use a .row wrapper.

**Solution 1**

I removed `justify-content-center` because it cant give gap between cols, so use `justify-content-around`.

```css
.price-selection {
  border: 1px solid #8ABE57;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row m-0 justify-content-around element">
  <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
    <p class="price">one</p>
    <p class="period">one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
    <p class="price">two</p>
    <p class="period">two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
    <p class="price">three</p>
    <p class="period">three</p>
  </div>     
</div>
```

**Solution 2**

you can also use CSS for equally gap between cols ( no bootstrap class for `space-evenly` ).

```
.element {     
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```css
.price-selection {
 border: 1px solid #8ABE57;
 display: inline-block;
}
.element {     
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row m-0 element">
  <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
    <p class="price">one</p>
    <p class="period">one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
    <p class="price">two</p>
    <p class="period">two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
    <p class="price">three</p>
    <p class="period">three</p>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct markup for what you're trying to achieve:

```css
.price-selection {
  border: 1px solid #8ABE57;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 product-info-subtitle cuanto-pagar">
      <p>¿Cuánto quieres pagar?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
          <p class="price">one</p>
          <p class="period">one</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
          <p class="price">two</p>
          <p class="period">two</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
          <p class="price">three</p>
          <p class="period">three</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The important part is: i wrapped the `col`'s in a `row` which has the class of `justify-content-around`.

The `row` part fixes the margin/paddings of Bootstrap grid on various screen sizes.

The `justify-content-around` gives it `justify-content: space-evenly`. Currently Bootstrap only has `justify-content-around` and `justify-content-between`. However, since it was released, flexbox was added a new value for justify-content (which will probably get added to Bootstrap), which is `space-evenly`. However, Bootstrap doesn't yet have a class for it.

If you want to space your elements evenly, you'll need to add it in CSS yourself:

```css
.price-selection {
  border: 1px solid #8ABE57;
  display: inline-block;
}
.justify-content-evenly {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 product-info-subtitle cuanto-pagar">
      <p>¿Cuánto quieres pagar?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row justify-content-evenly">
        <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
          <p class="price">one</p>
          <p class="period">one</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
          <p class="price">two</p>
          <p class="period">two</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 price-selection text-center">
          <p class="price">three</p>
          <p class="period">three</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To better understand the difference between various types of spacing in flexbox, here's a graphical explanation: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/#article-header-id-1

Comment: @Nisharg, because at the time, your answer did not fix the main problem, which was having `.col` as direct child of another `.col`.

Comment: yep you are right but you can also do comment below so i will change it

Comment: I've had very negative experiences with that. I learned (the hard way) it's better to provide the correct answer.

Comment: thanks for that bro but we are beginner at SO and you are at high level ( because of high reputation ) so, if we are doing mistake, comment below, dont give `-1` rank

Comment: In principle, you are right, in practice, my time is limited. Sometimes, when I think it's too much to explain, I don't comment.

Comment: Appreciated by your explanation,  +1.